# Adding border with 2 colors to circular image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Found below is an image of the final output of what I'm trying to create. The part I'm having trouble with is the two color border.

I know I can control all sides of the border with a `border-top` or `border-bottom`. However since the image has a radius of 50%. The border width starts off thick then shrinks as you reach the middle.

Even when I added a `border-left` and `border-right` the two colors aren't connecting evenly.

```css
.testImage {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 7px solid red;
    border-bottom: 7px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/175" class="testImage" alt="img=1" />
```

[image]

Comment: As you saw trying to reproduce this effect, it can not be done using `border` HTM attributes. You would have to reproduce this on drawing 2 half circle (here 1 is brown on top, and the other one is white).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved with a little trickery, wrapping your image in a container. The `border-radius` property is a bit misleading, so you have to think of the four sides and see how you can create the same effect.

First you should ensure you have the dual-border effect in place.

```css
.image-border {
  display: inline-block; /* Fits the wrapper to the size of the image */
  overflow: hidden; /* Keeps the image inside the container */
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red red blue blue; /* Define colosr for top, right, bottom, and left sides */
}

.image-border > img {
  display: block; /* Prevent baseline alingment (space below image) */
}
```

```html
<div class="image-border">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/175" alt="img=1" />
</div>
```

Now the only issue is that the border is at a 45 degree "offset". You can fix this easily with transforms:

```css
.image-border {
  display: inline-block; /* Fits the wrapper to the size of the image */
  overflow: hidden; /* Keeps the image inside the container */
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red red blue blue; /* Define colosr for top, right, bottom, and left sides */
  transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Make the borders look aligned to the horizontal axis */
}

.image-border > img {
  display: block; /* Prevent baseline alingment (space below image) */
  transform: rotate(45deg); /* Cancel the container's transform */
}
```

```html
<div class="image-border">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/175" alt="img=1" />
</div>
```

There are other methods, such as a gradient set as the background-image, with a `padding` or transparent border to let it show. This one is a fun trick, so I figured you might learn more from this one!

Comment: wow!! Thank you so much. Especially for the notes in the text. I had a feeling the border-radius was the piece that was causing the trouble. I really like this, definitely learned something today. Thank you!

Comment: I did have one more question. The smaller blue circle in the corner with the icon. I noticed when I position it absolute that even if I change the z-index, that the element is behind the border. So it gets sandwhiched above the image and below the border. Any ideas?

Comment: Glad to help! That is because of the `overflow: hidden` rule which hides anything outside the boundaries of the block: the circle, in this case. To go around it, you can wrap your `.image-border` in another `<div>` (say `.image-block`), be sure to give it `position: relative`. You can then add your smaller icon, with `position: absolute`, as a sibling element to the `.image-border`, and you can place it where you want. To recap, the structure of your markup would be: `<div class="image-block"><div class="image-border"><img/></div><div class="image-icon"></div></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.container {
  position: relative;
  
  display: inline-block;
}

div.half__circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  
  background: red;
  
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
}

div.half__circle:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;  
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
}

div.half__circle:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: blue;  
  border-radius: 50px 50px 0 0;
  
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}

.image {
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  height: calc(100% - 30px);

  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="half__circle"></div>
  <div class="half__circle"></div>
  <img class="image" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.striking.ly/page/images/custom/dUET9v8VSJquJGPLePed_tsquared_no_angle.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The background method with few line of codes:

```css
.testImage {
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 7px;
  background: linear-gradient(red 50%, blue 0);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/175" class="testImage" alt="img=1" >
```